# Node.js and Express with socket.io on Heroku - H12 & H13 errors

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

Currently building a project running a Heroku `Standard-1X` dyno with Node, Express and Socket.io. The premise of the app is rather simple: People search from a client for items (stored under the hood as Dicts, like so):

```
    ['Item':'Coffee', 
    'Id':0247508725,
    'Location': 'Baker Street']
```

and select them, then the items key values are pushed to the Node server and stored in a list. The list is than retrieved by the rest of the clients in 'real time'. Clients are all natively built Swift iOS apps

I ran it for the first time with roughly 60 users, all searching and adding items simultaneously. The results from the Heroku dashboard were horrendous:

[image: Heroku Dashboard]

I thought I had been thorough in testing, I had never seen so many H12 & H13 errors. Part of me thinks it might be inefficient code on my server side, or simply the lack of proper Node implementation to handle so many requests so I'm not constantly waiting on I/O because of the whole single threaded-ness deal.

Here is an example of the function server side that runs to add an item on that list:

```
clientSocket.on("additionToList", function(Location,Item,Id){
  client.query("INSERT q_venue_list (item_name, item_id, at_location) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",[Item,Id,Location], function(err, result) {
if(err) {
  return console.error('error running insert', err);
}
io.sockets.in(Location).emit('updateList');
  });
});
```

When the clients sockets in room `Location`receive the `'updateList'` command, they pull the new list. Storage and retrieval all work fine, but for some reason with all these people, everything got bogged down and was extremely lagged. **I hardly know what I'm doing** but I'm just trying to understand where I might be going wrong. I can't cluster because I only get access to one core, so would be next best option be to explore async? Could it be horrible device signal, coupled with waiting on I/O that causes all the timeouts?

I'm just looking to understand this, any help is appreciated. Let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: Without more of your code I can't really tell what's up from down, but it seems like that many errors suggests that you are not utilizing Node's asynchronous potential.

Comment: @sova you're probably right. Have you ever come across any resources that nicely lay out these concepts in more layman terms for someone who is learning on the fly?

Comment: Well, recently just getting a grasp of the callback model myself, I can highly recommend codeschool's course "real-time web with node.js"    Some videos and interactive exercises to help one get the gist.  Try reading up on the javascript Event Loop as a nice complement.

Comment: are you attaching socket.io to the http server, or do you have socket.io in each expresses route?

Comment: @DavidGatti It was all attached to the http server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this thread experiencing odd issues like this, I eventually figured out what the issue was. I was not releasing the socket layer and disconnecting (`socket.disconnect`) on `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillResignActive`. This was causing that socket on the backend to wait until timeout (55 seconds). The whole time it was waiting, it was bogging down the rest of the event loop; consequently, other incoming requests would wait, then they, too, would time out.

**tl;dr**: be diligent about opening and closing your sockets. Don't forget to close them when the user exits the app.